# Extract nested type without passing it twice?

Tags: scala

This is just a basic example, but can the last trait be rewritten to avoid using a 2 type (T ,U ) setup in a way that somehow extracts or infers T by just using M? I'm more asking about the type system without explicit objects, but perhaps that is the only way?

```
trait Data[T]{
  val x:T
}

trait Meta[T<:Data[T]]{
  val m:T
}

trait Overall[T, M<:Meta[T] ] {
 def review(t:T): M
}

//assume we want to work with the nested data type Int
case class Helper extends Overall[Int,Meta[Int]]
```

Incorrect illustration of what I'm asking:

```
//extract T by however Overall is finally defined?
trait Overall[ M<:Meta[T] ] {
    def review(t:T): M
}

case class Helper extends Overall[Meta[Int]]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you use a type member for `Meta`:

```
trait Meta {
  type T <: Data[T] 
  val m: T
}

trait Overall[M <: Meta] {
  def review(t: M#T): M
}

case class IntData(x: Int) extends Data[Int]

case class Helper extends Overall[Meta { type T = IntData }] {
  def review(t: IntData) = ???
}
```

---

Are you sure, though, that you want to define `T <: Data[T]`. Because that makes little sense:

```
case class Helper extends Overall[Meta { type T = IntData }] {
  def review(t: IntData) = new Meta {
    type T = IntData
    val m = IntData(1234)
  }
}

<console>:14: error: overriding type T in trait Meta with bounds <: Data[this.T];
 type T has incompatible type
           type T = IntData
                ^
```

That way, the only possibility to define a `Data` type is like

```
case class IntData() extends Data[IntData] { val x = this } // !?!

case class Helper extends Overall[Meta { type T = IntData }] {
  def review(t: IntData) = new Meta {
    type T = IntData
    val m = IntData()
  }
}
```

Probably that's not what you want.

Comment: yeah I think I need to go back to the drawing board on the reasons I need to do this in the first place, but this gives me a lot to consider!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can derive the type directly like you want. However, you can hide a type from the signature by making it a type variable instead.

```
trait Overall[T] {
  type M <: Meta[T]
  def review(t:T): M
}

case class Helper extends Overall[Int] {
  override type M = Meta[Int]
  def review(t: Int): Meta[Int] = null;
}
```

You'll still have to declare it in subclasses, but not when using the class.